# Send data to server is not working

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

i have created employee table on server. in that table i have four fields

Table look like this

**emp_id ,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary** this is four columns i want to insert data into that

my php file code is below..

```
$emp_id=$_POST["emp_id"];
$emp_name=$_POST["emp_name"];
$emp_address=$_POST["emp_address"];
$emp_salary=$_POST["emp_salary"];



// Insert Query 
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ".
       "(emp_id,emp_name, emp_address,emp_salary) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('$emp_id','$emp_name','$emp_address','$emp_salary')";
mysql_select_db('demo');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";


mysql_close($con);
```

i have send data from iOS like this

```
int emp_id = 01;
    NSString * emp_name = @"jit";
    NSString * emp_address = @"Nashik";
    int emp_salary = 25000;


     NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"emp_id=%demp_name=%@emp_address=%@emp_salary=%d",emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary];

     NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [str UTF8String] length: [str length]];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~jeetulives/hello.php"]];

     [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
     [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

     NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

Error Log is

**xammpconnection sucessful Could not enter data: Data truncated for column 'emp_id' at row 1**

where may i go wrong help me sort out this.

thanks in advance...

Comment: put & between two parameteres like NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"emp_id=%d&emp_name=%@&emp_address=%@&emp_salary=%d",emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary]; Try this if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Put a "," after every value

Or

create a json string like below

```
 NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"emp_id\"=\"%d\",\"emp_name\"=\"%@\",\"emp_address\"=\"%@\",\"emp_salary\"=\"%d\"",emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary];
```

Or

Instead of passing NSData object directly pass the json string

Answer (score 0):

It was my silly mistake. Missing **&** between my passing string using this **&** you have to separate out the string.

My Correct code is

```
    int emp_id = 1;
    NSString * emp_name = @"Jit";
    NSString * emp_address = @"Nashik";
    int emp_salary = 25000;


    NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"emp_id=%d&emp_name=%@&emp_address=%@&emp_salary=%d",emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary];


    // NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"emp_id\"=\"%d\",\"emp_name\"=\"%@\",\"emp_address\"=\"%@\",\"emp_salary\"=\"%d\"",emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary];


     NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [str UTF8String] length: [str length]];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~jeetulives/hello.php"]];

     [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
     [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

     NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

PHP file is perfect no issue with php file.